# How to make semi circle (arc) view in layout

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to make an arc view in my layout , I've tried to use a library but it doesn't works fine , how can I make an arch view like this and attache a button to it for example   :

[image]

I've tried some codes but they wasn't displaying properly on tablet and different size of screens

Comment: Which library did you try?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for API >= 21, then vector path may be a solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="500.0"
android:viewportHeight="500.0"
android:width="50dp"
android:height="50dp">

<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:pathData="M0 0 H500 V300 H-500"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:pathData="M0,300 L500 300, A4,2 0 1,1 0,210 Z"/>

</vector>
```

What we are doing here is draw two vector paths (maybe possible with one path only, but for demonstration purposes I am going to explain with two paths).
[image]
The first path

```
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:pathData="M0 0 H500 V300 H-500 Z"/>
```

In the first line we setup the color for the shape. Then in the second line actual working starts.

- M0 0, this moves the cursor to (x,y) = (0,0)
- H500, this draws a horizontal line from (0,0) to (500,0)
- V300, this draws a vertical line from (500,0) to (500,300)
- H-500, this draws a line from (500,300) to (0, 300)
- Z, this closes the path, i.e. joins the first (0,0) and last (500,300) points together.

So, we end up drawing a nice rectangle shape (try to comment the second path's code to see that rectangle).

More explanation to come (for path 2)...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom solution I've came up with.

It's basically using

- view with height of x dp as main box
- another view with oval shape as background
- adjusting the oval shape below the rectangular view above, about half it's height

For various screens you have to define the height/margin values in values.xml files though, but works fine I guess.

[image]

inside of which can be seen like this

[image]

Here's the [layout file](https://gist.github.com/monsterbrain/e215ea085643b0ae74a1b9c550ec22e8) for this.

Not an elegent solution, but someone might benefit from this I think.